# how to make a message without wrapping in span in react-intl

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, formatmessage

i have a problem with yahoo/react-intl thats i want to make messages in string type but when im using FormattedMessage it gives me message wrapped in span and thats not cool. 
i tried formatMessage and that not working too.
i be very thankful for any help or advise this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {FormattedMessage} from 'react-intl';
export default {
    items: [
        {
            name: <FormattedMessage id='app.dashboard'/>,
            url: '/dashboard',
            icon: 'icon-speedometer',
            badge: {
                variant: 'info',
                text: 'New',
            },
        },
        {
            title: true,
            name:  <FormattedMessage id='app.dashboard'/>,
            // optional wrapper object
            wrapper: {
                // required valid HTML5 element tag
                element: 'strong',
                // optional valid JS object with JS API naming ex: { className: "my-class", style: { fontFamily: "Verdana" }, id: "my-id"}
                attributes: {},
            },
            // optional class names space delimited list for title item ex: "text-center"
            class: '',`enter code here`
        },
```

Comment: Question is not that much clear could you add some more code detailed

Comment: BEJGAM SHIVA PRASAD look my code here is working but it gives me data wrapped in span and i dont like it and formatMessage didnt work to...

Answer (score 8):

for use in jsx:

**it's rendered as a `<span>`:**

```
<FormattedMessage id='app.dashboard'/>
```

**it's rendered as an `<option>`:**

```
<FormattedMessage id='app.dashboard' children={msg=> <option>{msg}</option>}/>
```

or:

```
<FormattedMessage id='app.dashboard' tagName="option"/>
```

**it's rendered to `nothing`:**

```
<FormattedMessage id='app.dashboard' children={msg=> <>{msg}</>}/>
```

or:

```
<FormattedMessage  id="app.dashboard">{txt => txt}</FormattedMessage>
```

**To use it in a component, you can use `formatMessage()` like this:**

```js
const App=()=>{
  const value = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'header.nav.login' });
  return(<div>{value}</>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you inject the `intl` context by yourself, Then you can use the [`formatMessage`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#formatmessage) function.

For example, in your case:

```
items: [
  { 
    name: intl.formatMessage({id:'app.dashboard'});
  }
]
```

To get `intl` in your component you have two choices:

1. get it from your component's context
2. use [`injectIntl`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#injectintl) to get it in your props.

---

If you're not in a component, it gets slightly harder but I would just put the `id` instead of the formatted message in `name` and then use the react-intl context when available. Here, in the component that consumes and displays this list of items.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to upgrade react-intl to version 3.

In version 3, the `<FormattedMesage>` (and similarly others react-intl components) is rendering into `React.Fragment`.

If you want to render it to something else you can specify `textComponent` prop on `IntlProvider`, eg.:

```js
<IntlProvider textComponent="span" />
```

See info in [Migration Guide (v2 -> v3)](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-3x#breaking-api-changes).